# How to tell Windows Explorer to refresh its icons?

Tags: c, icons, windows-explorer, windows-shell

Once my installer finishes installing new versions of my application's exe, I'd like to tell Explorer to use the new exe's icons for its shortcuts.  However, I cannot figure out how to do this.

From reading online, it looks like the problem is that the [system image list](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/sysimg) is caching an old version of the icon.  I tried calling [SHChangeNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762118%28VS.85%29.aspx) with a `SHCNE_UPDATEIMAGE` parameter.  I tried calling [SHUpdateImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762258%28VS.85%29.aspx).  I even tried the [sledgehammer approach](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell/browse_thread/thread/439e0ff1718f4377) of broadcasting `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`.  Nothing seems to work.

It's entirely possible that I'm just doing something wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

Warning: Very ugly test code follows.

```
#if 1
    // First attempt: using shell functions
    wchar_t icon_path[MAX_PATH];
    int icon_index;
    UINT icon_flags;

    IShellFolder *desktop_folder;
    IShellFolder *sub_folder;
    IExtractIcon *extract_icon;
    LPITEMIDLIST pidl;

    SHGetDesktopFolder(&desktop_folder);

    wchar_t *folder_path = L"C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Start Menu\\Programs\\MyCompany\\";
    desktop_folder->ParseDisplayName(NULL, NULL, folder_path, NULL, &pidl,
        NULL);
    desktop_folder->BindToObject(pidl, NULL, IID_IShellFolder,
        (void**) &sub_folder);
    sub_folder->ParseDisplayName(NULL, NULL, L"MyApp.lnk", NULL, &pidl,
        NULL);

    sub_folder->GetUIObjectOf(NULL, 1, (LPCITEMIDLIST*) &pidl,
        IID_IExtractIcon, NULL, (void**) &extract_icon);

    extract_icon->GetIconLocation(0, icon_path, MAX_PATH,
        &icon_index, &icon_flags);

    SHFILEINFO sfi;
    DWORD_PTR result = SHGetFileInfo(shortcut_path, 0, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), 
        SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_LARGEICON);
    SHUpdateImage(icon_path, icon_index, icon_flags, sfi.iIcon);
    // sfi.iIcon should be correct, but we'll try both, just for fun...
    SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEIMAGE, SHCNF_DWORD, NULL,
        (LPCVOID) icon_index);
    SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEIMAGE, SHCNF_DWORD, NULL,
        (LPCVOID) sfi.iIcon);
#else
    // Second attempt: broadcasting a settings change
    HKEY reg;
    RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        L"Control Panel\\Desktop\\WindowMetrics", 0, NULL, 0,
        KEY_SET_VALUE, NULL, &reg, NULL);
    DWORD value;
    value = 33;
    RegSetValueEx(reg, L"Shell Icon Size", 0, REG_DWORD, (BYTE*) &value,
        sizeof(value));
    value = 32;
    SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS,
        (int) L"WindowMetrics");
    RegSetValueEx(reg, L"Shell Icon Size", 0, REG_DWORD, (BYTE*) &value,
        sizeof(value));
    SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS,
        (int) L"WindowMetrics");
#endif
```

Comment: Have you tried just asking nicely? (Sorry, couldn't help it. ;)

Comment: @Dustin:  Let me try.  Start -> Run -> "explorer --refresh-my-icons-please".  Explorer replies: "The path '--refresh-my-icons-please' does not exist or is not a directory."  Nope, didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sledge-hammer approach is the one I've seen used to get this done.  An oops in your code though, the "Shell Icon Size" value is a `REG_SZ`, not a `REG_DWORD`.  Always VERIFY() the API function return values...