# Folder icon change doesn't take effect

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, registry

I change the default system folder icon via registry key

```
Reg := TRegistry.Create; 
try 
  Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  Reg.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons', True);
  Reg.WriteString('3', 'C:\MyIcon.icl,0');
finally
  RegFile.Free;
end;
```

I can change registry values, but the problem is I need to restart the OS for it to take effect.

To fix it I tried:

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0);
```

and:

```
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, nil, nil);
```

It works on WinXP but does not on Win7.

How can i fix it on Win7?

Comment: delete *IconCache.db* could avoid a reboot

Comment: i have tried delete IconCache.db. It doesnt work

Comment: icl file is icon library

Comment: I've tried to translate even the way how TortoiseSVN does its *force notifiation*, no success. It's described in the answer to [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/647316/960757).

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757737/how-to-tell-windows-explorer-to-refresh-its-icons). specially the [sledgehammer approach](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell/Q54P8XGPQ3c). very nasty...

Comment: @kobik, that's how [`TortoiseSVN`](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/svn/tortoisesvn/trunk/src/Utils/ShellUpdater.cpp) does it (login: guest; no pass). However, even that had no effect when I've tried.

Comment: Try this one. Do not delete the Iconcache.db using explorer and while explorer process running, it will recreate the old copy. Instead, 1. close all explorer instance (from taskman), 2. go to ...Appdata\local folder and delete iconcache.db, and 3.restart explorer.

Comment: oops, I forgot something, in step 2, go to cmd prompt and delete the file

Answer (score 1):

Try to "end task" the process "explorer.exe" from task manager,

and start it again (Run -> explorer.exe),

if by this process you can see the updated icons, try to do this programmatically, so that you don't have to do a restart.